# Laravel clean install "putenv() has been disabled for security reasons"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just clean installed Laravel and am getting the following message not just upon install but also when running `composer update`:

> putenv() has been disabled for security reasons

The thing is, I've enabled `putenv()`, I've removed it from the `disable_functions` directive in PHP and even ran the following code snippet in a test file:

```
<?php

    if (putenv("TESTENV=yes")) {
        echo 'putenv is indeed enabled.';
    }
```

And it outputs "putenv is indeed enabled". So `putenv()` is enabled but artisan and Laravel are still having trouble using it for some reason.

Is Laravel disabling it on the application level?

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`